# RecieveBufferSize OutOfRangeException (.NET)

Tags: vb.net, tcp, tcpclient, outofrangeexception

(Before I start I know this title is awful if someone could think of a better name I'd love it)

I ran out of ideas to program, and found a post listing some things, so I made a simple local chat server. The server runs fine until I attempt to connect (via tcpClient)

The code from the client side is as follows:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    readData = "Connected."
    Msg()
    clientSocket.Connect("xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", 8888)
    serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()

    Dim outStream As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text & "$")
    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)
    serverStream.Flush()

    Dim ctThread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf GetMessage)
    ctThread.Start()
End Sub
```

Where the IP is my IPV4 static address.

On the server side:

```
Dim serverSocket As TcpListener = New TcpListener(ip, 8888)
    Dim clientSocket As TcpClient
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    serverSocket.Start()
    Msg("Server started.")
    While (True)
        counter += 1
        clientSocket = serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient()

        Dim bytesFrom(10024) As Byte
        Dim dataFromClient As String

        Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
        networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
        dataFromClient = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom)

        dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"))

        clientsList(dataFromClient) = clientSocket

        Msg(dataFromClient & "joined the server.")
        Dim client as new handleClient
        client.startClient(clientSocket, dataFromClient, clientsList)
    End While
```

When I attempt to connect the client, the server throws [**this**](https://pastebin.com/J2ycRXKd)

I do not understand why this is happening. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1. Please post a *full* stack trace 2. Your problem seems very similiar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697819/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-size

Comment: @Freggar erm I'm very much a newbie when it comes to programming in comparison to others.. How would I get a full stack trace?

Comment: @David Check [this](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/) and then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/945203/4934172).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: @Freggar Edited with full Stack

Comment: @David have you looked at the SO post I linked? The guy has literally the same error as you, and there is a well explained answer on how to do things correctly.

Comment: @Freggar I did look at it. The problem is that is in C#, I'm using .Net, and the line `byte[] inStream = new byte[4096]` is making no sense to me as I have no idea how to program that in VB

Comment: @David C# also "uses" .Net and is the dominant language that is pushed by Microsoft so sadly you will more often find  C# code than VB.NET. You can use a code converter for small code snippets like in that answer: https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

Comment: @Freggar Helpful website, and it worked. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, CInt(clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize))
```

`ReceiveBufferSize` represents the *internal* buffer size used by the TCP socket, you're not supposed to use that in your code (there's also no need to call `CInt()`, as it is already an Integer).

You already have your own buffer, which's length you are supposed to specify:

```
networkStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, bytesFrom.Length)
```

The third parameter indicates *the maximum number of bytes* that you can receive in one `Read()` call. Obviously this can't exceed your buffer's length, which is why you need to give it exactly that (or a smaller value, if you want to read a more specific amount of bytes).

Comment: The problem with this is that bytesFrom was originally 'Dim-ed' incorrectly, `Dim inStream() As Byte = New Byte((4096) - 1) {}` ***plus*** changing to bytesFrom.length solved the issue

Comment: @David : Actually it wasn't. `Dim bytesFrom(10024) Byte` is also valid syntax and would've worked just as fine (although 10025 is a rather odd buffer size). Anyway, glad I could help!

Comment: Nah, when I did that, it said that Byte() could not be converted to Byte.. Which seemed odd to me. Might be an issue with the buffer size (which I agree is rather odd)

Comment: @David : I'm curious, on what line did that occur? Because both ways are valid syntax.

Comment: Never mind. >.> I was programming to quickly, and errors weren't disappearing between keystrokes. Both are valid