# The specified argument is outside the range of valid values

Tags: vb.net

Exception thrown:

> 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' in System.dll An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in
>   System.dll  The specified argument is outside the range of valid
>   values. Parameter name: size'

With this code:

```
  For infiniteCounter = 1 To 2
        infiniteCounter = 1
        serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream()
        Dim buffSize As Integer
        Dim inStream(10024) As Byte
        buffSize = 
    clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize
        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize)
        Dim returndata As String =
        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream)
        readData = "" + returndata
        msg()
    Next
```

At this line, `serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize)`

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RecieveBufferSize OutOfRangeException (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51357428)

Comment: Your `NetworkStream` reads a number of bytes (`buffSize`) that may not be equal to the size of the buffer (`inStream`). `Dim buffSize As Integer = clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize` `Dim inStream(buffSize) As Byte`. `serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, buffSize)`. The `infiniteCounter` is weird.

Comment: @Jimi : You are correct, but as (briefly) explained in my answer above it is better to avoid using `ReceiveBufferSize` altogether and instead define your own size. That way you know that at least this part of your code will behave consistently across all machines it is run on.

Comment: @Visual Vincent   Yes, of course. Nobody keeps the default. It's one of the parameters that is part of the configuration you apply to your specific implementations and needs. Here, you could assume it has been already modified. Probably not `= 10024`, though.

Comment: @Visual Vincent  Oh gosh! What did you do to the OP? Is he gone?

Comment: The range of 1 to 2 is an infinity on Planet WavyHand, dont you know

Comment: @Jimi : The OP never existed. He's just an iͨl͕̳ͪl͡u͓͠s͙̳ͩͬiͣ̈́o͔ͯͪ͏n͕.